# How to deploy Custom Object Permissions using Salesforce Migration Tool (ANT)?

Tags: deployment, migration-tool

We have a custom object in our development sandbox that we've removed Delete permissions on for a custom security profile.

In our package.xml, I've included the custom object and the custom security profile but when I deploy, the target org still has the delete permission set for the object and profile.

I verified that the `<allowDelete>` is set to false in the profile xml:

[image]

Modify All Data is not checked in the source profile and there were no errors during deployment.

How does one deploy Custom Object Permissions (object-level Read, Create, Edit, Delete, etc.) using the ANT-based Salesforce Migration Tool?

Comment: This only works on custom profiles. Are you sure you're using a custom profile?

Comment: Yes, it's a custom security profile.

Comment: Some permissions require other permissions. Did you get an error, like maybe you've got Modify All Data specified on the profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the profile in the target org was in an invalid state. While I did not receive any errors during the deployment of that profile, I did receive an error if I tried to manually edit that profile:

> Error: Invalid Data.
>   Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   Permission Import Solutions depends on permission(s): Delete Solutions, Edit Solutions

Once I unchecked `Import Solutions` in the source profile, I was able to deploy the profile change to remove Delete permissions from my custom object.

On a side note, but still relevant to this problem, a second profile I'm trying to deploy would not remove the Delete permissions on my custom object, but it does have Modify All Data permission enabled, preventing the update.